# maven Out Of Memory Error

Tags: java, maven, out-of-memory

i am running `mvn clean install` and getting gc limit exceed problem

`mvn -version`

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-04T01:09:06+05:30)
Maven home: F:\Maven_Home\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

also set the `MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit` but issue continues .

here is error stacktrace

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.util.Util.getInputStreamAsCharArray(Util.java:578)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.util.Util.getFileCharContent(Util.java:414)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.CompilationUnit.getContents(CompilationUnit.java:77)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.BatchCompilerRequestor.acceptResult(BatchCompilerRequestor.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.handleInternalException(Compiler.java:699)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processCompiledUnits(Compiler.java:612)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:458)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main.performCompilation(Main.java:4156)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main.compile(Main.java:1703)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.compiler.jdt.JDTCompiler.compileInProcess(JDTCompiler.java:349)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.compiler.jdt.JDTCompiler.performCompile(JDTCompiler.java:109)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:785)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

[image: jvisualvm output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch the process in jvisualvm (it is a standard part of the JDK). There you can see whether the memory is correctly set to 2048m. If not, give the parameter to Maven directly. If you see in jvisualvm that the parameter is set correctly, you just need more memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a dependency for it in the `pom.xml`, see [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/usage.html) for details. Note I've added in the configuration to what's on that link.

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.1</version>
          <configuration>
              <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```